# How can I define the number of guesses in accordance with the length of the word while looping in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, while-loop

I'd like to get some help with coding that part when the program asks for inputs as many times as the length of the word.

So, when we start the program it picks a word randomly from the array and for example if the word that we're looking for is "team" that means we have four guesses.

I was trying to solve it with the snippet below. It seems so easy but I'm missing something:

```
while(!guess.equals(choosenWord) && letters <= choosenWord.length()) {
                System.out.print("Your guess is: ");
                guess = sc.nextLine();
```

The next part which I need some hint is if we have some matches in characters, than the found character should be displayed and "-" sign should be shown anywhere else: for example the word is still "team" that we're looking for and our guess is "baby" than "--a-" will be displayed.

Thank you for the advices.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class FindTheWord {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        findTheWord();
    }

    public static void findTheWord() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] words = {
            "dog", "cat", "house", "love", "friend", "paper", "summer", "chips",
            "number", "file", "program", "lotto", "work", "funny", "database",
            "team", "profile", "facebook", "bean", "winter", "spring", "java", 
            "examination", "hospital", "birth", "baby", "newborn", "airplane",
            "kindergarten", "autumn"};

        int randomWord = (int) (Math.random() * 31);
        String choosenWord = " ";
        int letters = 0;
        String guess = " ";
        char ch = ' ';

        for (int i = 0; i < words[randomWord].length(); i++) {
            choosenWord = words[randomWord];

        }
        for (int j = 0; j < choosenWord.length(); j++) {
            letters = choosenWord.length();


        while(!guess.equals(choosenWord) && letters <= choosenWord.length()) {
            System.out.print("Your guess is: ");
            guess = sc.nextLine();

        }
        }
        System.out.println(words[randomWord]);
        System.out.println(letters);
    }


    }
```

Comment: why the `for` loops? you can increment the guess "counter" `letters` in the loop body, and your loop will stop once it reach the end of the word

Comment: You are totally right, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution with a ternary operator (`? :`):

```java
...
guess = sc.nextLine();
for (char c : chosenWord.toCharArray()) {
  System.out.print(guess.contains(String.valueOf(c)) ? c : '-');
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

> Complete solution (Tested and verified), Just you need to run it.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    findTheWord();
}

public static void findTheWord() {

    //Init
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] words = {
            "dog", "cat", "house", "love", "friend", "paper", "summer", "chips",
            "number", "file", "program", "lotto", "work", "funny", "database",
            "team", "profile", "facebook", "bean", "winter", "spring", "java",
            "examination", "hospital", "birth", "baby", "newborn", "airplane",
            "kindergarten", "autumn"};

    String randomWord = words[(int) (Math.random() * 31)];
    String guess = "";

    //Start Guessing
    for (int i = 0; i <= randomWord.length(); i++) {

        if (!guess.equals(randomWord)) {
            System.out.print("Your guess is: ");
            guess = sc.nextLine();
            String result = checkGuessMatch(randomWord, guess);
            if (!result.isEmpty())
                System.out.println(result);
        } else {
            System.out.println("#################################");
            System.out.println("############SUCCESS#############");
            System.out.println("##########THE WORD WAS###" + guess);
            System.out.println("#################################");
            return;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("####GAME OVER###");
    System.out.println("THE WORD WAS = " + randomWord);
}

public static String checkGuessMatch(String word, String guess) {
    Boolean sameIndexIsExist = false;
    char[] wordChars = word.toCharArray();
    char[] guessChars = guess.toCharArray();
    String target = "";

    for (int i = 0; (i < word.length()); i++) {

        if (i < guess.length() && guessChars[i] == wordChars[i]) {
            target = target + guessChars[i];
            sameIndexIsExist = true;
        } else
            target = target + "-";
    }
    if (!sameIndexIsExist)
        return "";
    else return target;

}
```